# Parallel execution fails for XGBoost with R and OS-X

Tags: r, gcc, parallel-processing, openmp, xgboost

Can't have xgboost working parallel with R 3.5.1 and OS X 10.12.6. I followed this [instructions](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html#building-on-os%20x). It seems to be openMP OK when compiling C code, but when compiling in R, cannot find the `-fopenmp` option and parallel execution does not work.

**Makevars**

```
cat ~/.R/Makevars 
CC=gcc-7
CXX=g++-7
CXX1X=g++-7
CXX11=g++-7
CXX14=g++-7
CXX17=g++-7

SHLIB_OPENMP_CFLAGS=-fopenmp
SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS=-fopenmp
SHLIB_OPENMP_FCFLAGS=-fopenmp
SHLIB_OPENMP_FFLAGS=-fopenmp
```

I tried gcc-8 too without success.

**Experiments:**

- Compile C code: `xgboost$ make -j4` => seems to work, `-fopenmp` compiler option is included: `g++-7 -c -DDMLC_LOG_CUSTOMIZE=1 -std=c++11 -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Iinclude   -Idmlc-core/include -Irabit/include -I/include -O3 -funroll-loops -msse2 -fPIC -fopenmp src/common/common.cc -o build/common/common.o`
- From source: `R-package$ R CMD INSTALL .` => `checking whether OpenMP will work in a package... no` and `g++-7 -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.5.1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I../..//include -I../..//dmlc-core/include -I../..//rabit/include -I../../ -DXGBOOST_STRICT_R_MODE=1 -DDMLC_LOG_BEFORE_THROW=0 -DDMLC_ENABLE_STD_THREAD=1 -DDMLC_DISABLE_STDIN=1 -DDMLC_LOG_CUSTOMIZE=1 -DXGBOOST_CUSTOMIZE_LOGGER=1 -DRABIT_CUSTOMIZE_MSG_ -DRABIT_STRICT_CXX98_  -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -g -O2 -c xgboost_R.cc -o xgboost_R.o`

It seems that R is not taking the `SHLIB_OPENMP_*` from Makevars options into account. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to hcho3 (https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/2503)

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=gcc-7 -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++-7 -DR_LIB=ON
make
make install
```

The last make install may fail. If that happens, run

```
# still inside build/
cd R-package
mv src/libxgboost.dylib src/xgboost.so # in my case 'mv src/xgboost.dylib src/xgboost.so'
R CMD INSTALL .
```

**His explaination:** 
So far I didn't have much success with modifying Makevars, since it gets overwritten by the configure script in R-package. When it comes to applying custom build options, it's IMO much easier to use CMake, which will generate configure and other build files in the R package (hence R-package directory gets generated under the build/) Only flaw I've seen so far with CMake is that it generates shared lib named libxgboost.dylib, whereas R expects xgboost.so